# Bazel Build Command - Is possible to skip "Test" Targets and Rules?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I wish to run `bazel build :...all` command and skip `test` rules and targets.  Is this possible?

I can conceive of two ways to distinguish the tests, either by their type (cc_test in my case), or by pattern-matching on the name, as the project I'm working in suffixes all test rules/targets with "_test".

Please, refrain from making comments telling me that I should always build and run tests upon compilation, unless Bazel actually makes it technically impossible to use "all" wildcard and also filter out all tests.  We have a tiered system where builds and tests are all run together, and then after success, another system just builds the minimum artifacts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [bazel query](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html). It's quite powerful so I advise to read through the documentation page to design the query command precisely. To quickly answer your concrete question, I think this will work for you:

`bazel query '//... except kind(.*test, //...)' | xargs bazel build`

Comment: Thanks very much! I did see the query language and it was clearly powerful, but the documentation talks about it in the context of reporting and analysis.  It even says "how do people use this", but there's no mention of piping the list to bazel build command.  brilliant.   It got me past the initial problem, I'm still surprised to see it building `external/com_google_googletest/libgtest.so`

Comment: Oh, but xargs doesn't work on windows.  trying put together the dos alternative.

Comment: for /f %a in ('"bazel query kind(cc_library, ...:all)"') do (bazel --batch build --cpu=x86_windows_msvc %a)

Comment: Note to others, there is a significant nuance regarding the performance of this method.  The bazel build command is launched and run once for each target. It doesn't benefit from concurrent builds and is just generally slower than when the `bazel build` command is used alone.

Comment: Can't one use the testOnly attribute to filter the labels?

Comment: Can they? That doesn't seem like a possibility based on how I read the doc.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to hlopko's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543959/427652.

#### Query `testonly` targets

https://bazel.build/query/language#attr

```bash
bazel query 'attr(testonly, 1, //...)'
```

#### Query non-`testonly` targets

```bash
bazel query 'attr(testonly, 0, //...)'
```

#### Put it all together

```bash
bazel query 'attr(testonly, 0, //...)' | xargs bazel build
```